# Using converters with xstream when an element has a value and child elements

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have a string of XML that looks like this:

```
<e1 atr1="3" atr2="asdf">
<e1b atr3="3" atr4="asdf">
    <e1c atr5="3" atr6="asdf"/>
    TestValue1
</e1b>
<e1b atr3="3" atr4="asdf">
    <e1c atr5="3" atr6="asdf"/>
    TestValue2
</e1b>
</e1>
```

It is different than other XML I have parsed in the past because the e1b elements have values `TestValue1` and `TestValue2` as well as child elements (`e1c`).

If an element has both attributes and a value, you have to create a custom converter for xstream to be able to parse it.  My attempt at that is below, but because the e1b element has attributes, child elements, AND a value, I'm not sure how to handle it.  In my converter, I have left off all references to the `e1c` child element.  What do I need to add to the converter to allow it to handle the `e1c` element correctly?  Right now, `e1c` values are not getting populated when I do a `xstream.fromXML()`.

```
public class e1Converter implements Converter {

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
    return e1b.class == clazz;
}

public void marshal(Object object, HierarchicalStreamWriter hsw,
        MarshallingContext mc) {
    e1b e = (e1b) object;
    hsw.addAttribute("atr3", e.getAtr3());
    hsw.addAttribute("atr4", e.getAtr4());

    hsw.setValue(e.getE1bValue());
}

public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader hsr,
        UnmarshallingContext uc) {

    e1b e = new e1b();
    e.setAtr3(hsr.getAttribute("atr3"));
    e.setAtr4(hsr.getAttribute("atr4"));
    e.setE1bValue(hsr.getValue());

    return e;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Jörg on the xstream mailing list:

> Actually you cannot. XStream cannot read mixed-mode XML i.e. XML where
>   text  and child elements are mixed at the same level. The readers will
>   simply act  in undefined behavior. This kind of XML does simply not
>   fit into the  hierarchical stream model of XStream. What's the value
>   of parent here:
>
> ```
> <parent> what <child/>is <child/> the <child/>value <child/>now? </parent
> ```
>
> Sorry, Jörg

Comment: This is a link to the mailing list thread mentioned above http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.xstream.user/7898